# How do I fix Browser Sync and Live Reload in my Gulpfile?

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch, livereload

I'm trying to get Browser Sync and Live Reload working in my gulp file but it doesn't want to run correctly.

I want to be able to detect any file change in 'src' and my 'templates' folder which are both contained within the root. The gulp file is detecting the changes in the src folder fine but the template files are not getting reloaded in the browser on save.

**Note:**

- I have the live reload chrome browser extension.
- I'm not compiling the templates folder but am compiling everything in src to the web destination folder.

**The Gulp File:**

```
// -------------------- Configuration Settings --------------------
var config = {};

//basics
config.siteName = 'Franklin';
config.proxyDomain = 'https://franklin.test';

//source directory
config.src = 'src/';

//twig templates
config.templates = 'templates';

//destinations
config.dest = 'web/';
config.destJS = config.dest + 'assets/js';
config.destCSS = config.dest + 'assets/css';
config.destFonts = config.dest + 'assets/fonts';
config.destPWA = config.dest;

//globs
config.globs = {
    templates : config.templates + '/**/*.twig',
    scss : config.src + 'scss/**/*.scss',
    js : {
        individual : config.src + 'js/individual/**/*.js',
        combined : [
            config.src + 'js/combined/libs/*.js',
            config.src + 'js/combined/plugins/*.js',
            config.src + 'js/combined/pluginSubs/*.js',
            config.src + 'js/combined/site/*.js',
            config.src + 'js/combined/site.js'
        ]
    },
    fonts : config.src + 'fonts/**/*',
    pwa : config.src + 'pwa/**/*',
    watched : [
        config.templates + '/**/*.twig',
        config.destJS + '/**/*.min.js',
        config.destCSS + '/**/*.min.css',
        config.destFonts + '/**/*',
        config.destPWA + '/**/*'
    ]
};

//browser sync
config.browserSync = {
    files: config.globs.watched,
    proxy: config.proxyDomain
};

// -------------------- Require Statements --------------------
var gulp           = require('gulp'),
    autoprefixer     = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    concat           = require('gulp-concat'),
    livereload       = require('gulp-livereload'),
    browserSync      = require('browser-sync').create(),
    newer            = require('gulp-newer'),
    notify           = require('gulp-notify'),
    plumber          = require('gulp-plumber'),
    rename           = require('gulp-rename'),
    sass             = require('gulp-sass'),
    size             = require('gulp-size'),
    uglify           = require('gulp-uglify'),
    watch            = require('gulp-watch'),
    path             = require('path'),
    cssnano          = require('gulp-cssnano'),
    sourcemaps       = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    lazypipe         = require('lazypipe'),
    fs               = require('fs');

// -------------------- Notification Icon Detection --------------------
/**
 * Checks to see if a file exists.
 *
 * @param filePath
 * @returns {*}
 */
function fileExists(filePath)
{
    try {
        return fs.statSync(filePath).isFile();
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
}

var iconPath = path.join(__dirname, 'gulp.png');
var icon = fileExists( iconPath ) ? iconPath : null;

// -------------------- Plumber Error Handler --------------------
var plumberErrorHandler = function(err) {
    console.log( 'plumber error! "' + err.message + '"' );
    notify.onError({
        title: config.siteName,
        message: "Error: <%= err.message %>",
        sound: 'Pop'
    });
    this.emit('end');
};

// -------------------- Processors --------------------
//individual scripts (not combined)
var jsIndividualScripts = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plumber, {errorHandler: plumberErrorHandler})
    .pipe(newer, { dest: config.destJS, ext: '.min.js' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest, config.destJS)
    .pipe(size, {showFiles: true})
    .pipe(uglify)
    .pipe(rename, { suffix: '.min' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest, config.destJS)
    .pipe(size, {showFiles: true});

//combined scripts
var jsCombinedScripts = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plumber, {errorHandler: plumberErrorHandler})
    .pipe(newer, config.dest + 'js/scripts.min.js')
    .pipe(concat, 'scripts.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest, config.destJS)
    .pipe(size, {showFiles: true})
    .pipe(uglify)
    .pipe(rename, { suffix: '.min' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest, config.destJS)
    .pipe(size, {showFiles: true});

//scss compiling
var scssProcessing = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plumber, {errorHandler: plumberErrorHandler})
    .pipe(sass, {outputStyle: ':compact'})
    .pipe(autoprefixer, 'last 2 version')
    .pipe(gulp.dest, config.destCSS)
    .pipe(size, {showFiles: true})
    .pipe(rename, { suffix: '.min' })
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init)
    .pipe(cssnano)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write, '.')
    .pipe(gulp.dest, config.destCSS)
    .pipe(size, {showFiles: true});

//fonts compiling
var fontsProcessing = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plumber, {errorHandler: plumberErrorHandler})
    .pipe(gulp.dest, config.destFonts);

//pwa compiling
var pwaProcessing = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plumber, { errorHandler: plumberErrorHandler })
    .pipe(gulp.dest, config.destPWA);


// -------------------- Tasks --------------------
//styles task
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    if ( browserSync.active ) {
        return gulp.src(config.globs.scss)
            .pipe(scssProcessing())
            .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
    }
    return gulp.src(config.globs.scss).pipe(scssProcessing());
});

//template task
gulp.task('templates', function() {
    if ( browserSync.active ) {
        return gulp.src(config.globs.templates)
            .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
    }
});

//scripts individual task
gulp.task('scripts-individual', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.globs.js.individual).pipe(jsIndividualScripts());
});

//scripts combined task
gulp.task('scripts-combined', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.globs.js.combined).pipe(jsCombinedScripts());
});

//fonts task
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.globs.fonts).pipe(fontsProcessing());
});

//pwa task
gulp.task('pwa', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.globs.pwa).pipe(pwaProcessing());
});

//watch task
gulp.task('live', function() {
    //watch all .scss files
    gulp.watch(config.globs.scss, ['styles']);

    //watch all twig template files
    gulp.watch(config.globs.templates, ['templates']);

    //watch each individual .js file
    watch(config.globs.js.individual).pipe(jsIndividualScripts());

    //watch all combined .js files
    gulp.watch(config.globs.js.combined, ['scripts-combined']);
});

//default task - one time styles and scripts
gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'templates', 'scripts-individual', 'scripts-combined', 'fonts', 'pwa']);

//start browser-sync server
gulp.task('serve-bs', ['live'], function() {
    browserSync.init(config.browserSync)
});

//start livereload
gulp.task('watch', ['live'], function() {
    livereload.listen();

    //watch for changes on transpired templates, css, and js files
    gulp.watch(config.globs.watched, function(event) {
        gulp.src(event.path)
            .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: plumberErrorHandler}))
            .pipe(livereload())
            .pipe(notify({
                    title: config.siteName,
                    message: event.type + ': ' + event.path.replace(__dirname, '').replace(/\\/g, '/') + ' was reloaded',
                    sound: 'Pop',
                    icon: icon
                })
            );
    });
});
```